# How can I merge together sentence objects?

Tags: python, algorithm, object, append

so I built a sentence tokenizer, that splits paragraphs into sentences, words, and characters... each of these being a data type. but the sentence system is a two stage system, because things like '. . .' throw it off, sense it goes one letter at a time, but it works fine if it's '...' with no spaces.

So the output is a bit spliced up, but if I can do some secondary processing on it, it will work perfectly. So that's where my question comes in... I'm not sure how to write a system that allows me to append each sentence that has no end sentence punctuation to the previous sentence without losing something along the way.

**here's examples of what the output looks like and what I need it to look like:**

> Some sentence that is spliced...
>
> and has a continuation
>
> this cannot be confused by U.S.A.
>
> In that
>
> last sentence...
>
> an abbreviation ended the sentence!

So sentence objects that do not end with a normal end of sentence delimiter i.e. '.', '?','!' need to be appended to the next sentence... until there is a sentence with a real end of sentence delimiter. and the other thing that makes this tough is '. . .' counts as a continuation, not the end of a sentence. So that will also need to be appended as well.

**this is how it needs to be:**

> Some sentence that is spliced... and has a continuation.
>
> this cannot be confused by U.S.A.
>
> In that last sentence... an abbreviation ended the sentence!

here's the code I was working with:

```
 last = []  
 merge = []
 for s in stream:
        if last:
           old = last.pop()
           if '.' not in old.as_utf8 and '?' not in old.as_utf8 and '!' not in old.as_utf8:

               new = old + s 
               merge.append(new)
           else:
               merge.append(s)
          last.append(s)
```

so there are a few problems with this method...

1. it only appends 1 sentence to another, but it does not keep appending if there are 2 or 3 that need to be added.
2. it drops the first sentence if it does not have any punctuation in it.
3. it does not deal with '. . .' as continuations. I know I did not wright anything for that in this, and that's because I'm not totally sure how to approach that problem, with sentences ending in an abbreviation, because I could count how many '.' are in the sentence, but it would be really thrown off by 'U.S.A.' because that counts as 3 periods.

so I've written an `__add__` method to the sentence class, so you can do `sentence + sentence` and that works as a way to append one to the other.

any help would be greatly appreciated on this. and let me know if any of this is unclear, and I will do my best to enplane it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want recursively? You want a recursive function or just anything that does the job?

Comment: it does not necessarily need to be recessive... but I may have used that word too loosely... what I mean is I wan't it to keep merging the same sentience until it gets to one with a real sentience break. the method of doing that is does not have to be recessive. I've updated the title, so that it is not misleading.

Comment: @WoLpH i think he's referring to receding gums

Comment: +1 for the extensive question and given info btw :)

Comment: @WoLpH thank's... I'm building off of your code. you had the right idea. I just need to modify it to work in my class structure. so thank you very much for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's some working code. Is this roughly what you need?
I'm not too happy with it yet, it looks a bit ugly imho but I want to know if it's the right direction.

```
words = '''Some sentence that is spliced...
and has a continuation.
this cannot be confused by U.S.A.
In that
last sentence... 
an abbreviation ended the sentence!'''.split()

def format_sentence(words):
    output = []

    for word in words:
        if word.endswith('...') or not word.endswith('.'):
            output.append(word)
            output.append(' ')
        elif word.endswith('.'):
            output.append(word)
            output.append('\n')
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unexpected result from word: %r' % word)

    return ''.join(output)

print format_sentence(words)
```

Output:

```
Some sentence that is spliced... and has a continuation.
this cannot be confused by U.S.A.
In that last sentence...  an abbreviation ended the sentence!
```

Comment: it would work, however... maybe I was a bit unclear on this, but I'm using a class structure... as in there is a character class, a word class, and a sentence class and because of this hierarchy it throws some difficulties into the system. one being that the only way you can append is with the + operator. but besides that you are on the right track I believe. and I really appreciate the help. here's an example of what the sentence data type looks like: [<__main__.Character object at 0x024FB350>, <__main__.Character object at 0x024FB370>].. it's basically a list of chars.

Comment: The reason I have to keep the char objects and not just make this thing way more simple, is because I'm parsing EPUB doc's with this and I have to keep the html intact, so in order to do that I have to make a class structure.

Comment: dang your code works really well... maybe I can try to make some sort of modification of it to work with my system. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AlexW.H.B.: I've updated the answer a little, it's a bit prettier now :)

Answer (score 2):

This 'algorithm' tries to makes sense of the input without relying on line endings, so that it *should* work correctly with some input like

```
born in the U.
S.A.
```

The code lends itself to being integrated into a state machine - the loop only remembers its current phrase and "pushes" finished phrases off onto a list, and gobbles one word at a time. Splitting on whitespaces is good.

Notice the ambiguity in case #5: that cannot be reliably solved (and it is possible to have such an ambiguity also with line endings. Maybe combining *both*...)

```
# Sample decoded data
decoded = [ 'Some', 'sentence', 'that', 'is', 'spliced.', '.', '.',
    'and', 'has', 'a', 'continuation.',
    'this', 'cannot', 'be', 'confused', 'by', 'U.', 'S.', 'A.', 'or', 'U.S.A.',
    'In', 'that', 'last', 'sentence...',
    'an', 'abbreviation', 'ended', 'the', 'sentence!' ]

# List of phrases
phrases = []

# Current phrase
phrase    = ''

while decoded:
    word = decoded.pop(0)
    # Possibilities:
    # 1. phrase has no terminator. Then we surely add word to phrase.
    if not phrase[-1:] in ('.', '?', '!'):
        phrase += ('' if '' == phrase else ' ') + word
        continue
    # 2. There was a terminator. Which?
    #    Say phrase is dot-terminated...
    if '.' == phrase[-1:]:
        # BUT it is terminated by several dots.
        if '..' == phrase[-2:]:
            if '.' == word:
                phrase += '.'
            else:
                phrase += ' ' + word
            continue
        # ...and word is dot-terminated. "by U." and "S.", or "the." and ".".
        if '.' == word[-1:]:
            phrase += word
            continue
        # Do we have an abbreviation?
        if len(phrase) > 3:
            if '.' == phrase[-3:-2]:
                # 5. We have an ambiguity, we solve using capitals.
                if word[:1].upper() == word[:1]:
                    phrases.append(phrase)
                    phrase = word
                    continue
                phrase += ' ' + word
                continue
        # Something else. Then phrase is completed and restarted.
        phrases.append(phrase)
        phrase = word
        continue
    # 3. Another terminator.
        phrases.append(phrase)
        phrase = word
        continue

phrases.append(phrase)

for p in phrases:
    print ">> " + p
```

Output:

```
>> Some sentence that is spliced... and has a continuation.
>> this cannot be confused by U.S.A. or U.S.A.
>> In that last sentence... an abbreviation ended the sentence!
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I'll play around with your code. again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code I ended up using, and it works great... this is largely based off of WoLpH code, so thank you very much!

```
    output = stream[:1]
    for line in stream:
            if output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '').endswith('...'):       
                output[-1] += line

            elif not output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '').endswith('.') and not output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '').endswith('?') and not output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '').endswith('!') and not output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '').endswith('"') and not output[-1].as_utf8.replace(' ', '')[-1].isdigit():
                if output[-1] != line:
                    output[-1] += line

            else:
                if output[-1] != line:
                    output.append(line)

    return output
```